# NSpredicate with date

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have this problem:

I want to filter a `NSMutableArray` with `NSPredicate`, but it returns this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfc7f950'
```

My code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"dataGiorno >= '%@'",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"31-12-2013"]]];

NSArray *filtered = [lista filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

My db row:

[Row DB](http://imageshack.com/a/img199/4894/p1c3.png)

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc ] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 00:00:00",@"2013-01-01" ]];
NSDate* secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 23:59:59",@"2013-12-31" ]];
NSPredicate *firstPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dataGiorno >= %@", firstDate];
NSPredicate *secondPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dataGiorno <= %@", secondDate];
NSPredicate *newCondition = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstPredicate, secondPredicate,nil]];
NSArray *filtered = [lista filteredArrayUsingPredicate:newCondition];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Juste replace this line :

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"dataGiorno >= '%@'",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"31-12-2013"]]];
```

With this one :

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dataGiorno >= '%@'",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"31-12-2013"]];
```

No need to use an extra NSString here.

Comment: The same error..:( I found the solution..now I edit the question...thanks